# Make p5js maze generator run faster

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've coded a Maze Generator based on the YouTube tutorial by TheCodingTrain.
I am trying to improve the project to have more possibilities for the mazes, but I'm struggling with performance issues. That's due to the big Canvas size since i want to get big mazes as outputs and since p5js is based on pixels I've got to do it this way.

Is there any way I can improve my code? Maybe there are some unnecessary parts in the draw() function I could leave out or a better algorithm in general? Thanks in advance!

```
// Variables
var cols, rows;
var w = 5;
var grid = [];
var canvX = 256*10;
var canvY = 144*10;

var current;

var stack = [];

// Setup
function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvX, canvY);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(0.5);
  rect(0, 0, canvX, canvY);
  cols = floor(width/w);
  rows = floor(height/w);
  frameRate(60);
  
  for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
      var cell = new Cell(i,j);
      grid.push(cell);
    }
  }
  
  current = grid[0];
}

// Draw
function draw() {
  background(51);
  for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    grid[i].show();
  }
  
  current.visited = true;
  current.highlight();
  // STEP 1
  var next = current.checkNeighbors();
  if(next) {
    next.visited = true;
    
    // STEP 2
    stack.push(current);
    
    
    // STEP 3
    removeWalls(current,next);
    
    // STEP 4
    current = next;
  } else if (stack.length > 0) {
    current = stack.pop();
  }
  if (current === grid[0]) {
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(canvX-w+2, canvY-w+2, w-4, w-4);
  }
}

function index(i,j) {
  if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols-1 || j > rows-1) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  return i + j * cols;
}

function Cell(i,j){
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
  this.visited = false;
  
  this.checkNeighbors = function() {
    var neighbors = [];
    
    var top    = grid[index(i,j-1)];
    var right  = grid[index(i+1,j)];
    var bottom = grid[index(i,j+1)];
    var left   = grid[index(i-1,j)];

    if(top && !top.visited) {
      neighbors.push(top);
    }
    if(right && !right.visited) {
      neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if(bottom && !bottom.visited) {
      neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if(left && !left.visited) {
      neighbors.push(left);
    }
    
    if(neighbors.length > 0) {
      var r = floor(random(0, neighbors.length));
      return neighbors[r];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
  this.highlight = function() {
    var x = this.i*w;
    var y = this.j*w;
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(x+2, y+2, w-4, w-4);
  }
  
  this.show = function() {
    var x = this.i*w;
    var y = this.j*w;
    stroke(0);
    if(this.walls[0]){
      line(x    ,y    ,x + w,y    );
    } 
    if(this.walls[1]){
      line(x + w,y    ,x + w,y + w);
    }
    if(this.walls[2]){
      line(x + w,y + w,x    ,y + w);
    }
    if(this.walls[3]){
      line(x    ,y + w,x    ,y    );
    }
    
    if(this.visited){
         noStroke();
      fill(255);
      rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
  }
}

function removeWalls(a, b) {
  
  var x = a.i - b.i;
  if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false;
  } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
  }
  
  var y = a.j - b.j;
  if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false;
  } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
  }
}
```

I ran the code on different devices. I don't have any device with a great performance and even my iPad did better than my 2012 iMac. So my equipment isn't that great which contributes to my problems

Comment: can you check if [this approach](https://editor.p5js.org/wonderflame/sketches/oqBRL5VY8) is better enough? If that okay I can write up an answer explaining

Answer (score 1):

The main performance issue stems from the shear number of cells and therefore the number of drawing commands per frame. The thing is the vast majority of the display is not changing from frame to frame. So instead of clearing the screen with a call to `background(51)` and then redrawing all cells, you can optimize your code by only drawing the cells that have changed in appearance.

```js
// Variables
var cols, rows;
var w = 5;
var grid = [];
var canvX = 256 * 10;
var canvY = 144 * 10;

var current;

var stack = [];

// Setup
function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvX, canvY);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(0.5);
  rect(0, 0, canvX, canvY);
  cols = floor(width / w);
  rows = floor(height / w);
  // frameRate(60);

  for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      var cell = new Cell(i, j);
      grid.push(cell);
    }
  }

  current = grid[0];

  // Only draw the background and *all* the cells in setup
  background(51);
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].show();
  }
}

// Draw
function draw() {
  // do *not* redraw all the cells in the draw function
  // background(51);
  // for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
  //   grid[i].show();
  // }

  current.visited = true;
  current.show();
  current.highlight();
  // STEP 1
  var next = current.checkNeighbors();
  if (next) {
    next.visited = true;

    // STEP 2
    stack.push(current);

    // STEP 3
    removeWalls(current, next);
    
    // Draw only the cells that may have changed
    current.show();
    next.show();

    // STEP 4
    current = next;
  } else if (stack.length > 0) {
    current = stack.pop();
  }
  if (current === grid[0]) {
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(canvX - w + 2, canvY - w + 2, w - 4, w - 4);
  }
}

function index(i, j) {
  if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols - 1 || j > rows - 1) {
    return -1;
  }

  return i + j * cols;
}

function Cell(i, j) {
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
  this.visited = false;

  this.checkNeighbors = function () {
    var neighbors = [];

    var top = grid[index(i, j - 1)];
    var right = grid[index(i + 1, j)];
    var bottom = grid[index(i, j + 1)];
    var left = grid[index(i - 1, j)];

    if (top && !top.visited) {
      neighbors.push(top);
    }
    if (right && !right.visited) {
      neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if (bottom && !bottom.visited) {
      neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if (left && !left.visited) {
      neighbors.push(left);
    }

    if (neighbors.length > 0) {
      var r = floor(random(0, neighbors.length));
      return neighbors[r];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  };
  this.highlight = function () {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(x + 2, y + 2, w - 4, w - 4);
  };

  this.show = function () {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    stroke(0);
    if (this.walls[0]) {
      line(x, y, x + w, y);
    }
    if (this.walls[1]) {
      line(x + w, y, x + w, y + w);
    }
    if (this.walls[2]) {
      line(x + w, y + w, x, y + w);
    }
    if (this.walls[3]) {
      line(x, y + w, x, y);
    }

    if (this.visited) {
      noStroke();
      fill(255);
      rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
  };
}

function removeWalls(a, b) {
  var x = a.i - b.i;
  if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false;
  } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
  }

  var y = a.j - b.j;
  if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false;
  } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Also, your sketch is very mesmerizing, thank you for sharing, and for posting your question with a runnable snippet!